# How to check the impact of predictive Model

Tags: machine-learning, python, ab-test, hypothesis-testing

Suppose that I build an email marketing campaign where the goal is to predict which members will make purchases or not and based on that change the marketing email campaigns. After we build the model, let's say we make recommendations to change the body of the marketing emails in a certain way. After one quarter, and having applied these changes, we observe that there is 10% increase in purchases with respect to last quarter or the same quarter last year. How do we know this 10% increase is the result of the model predictive power and the subsequent changes and not any other reason, such as external factors? Should we run A/B testing, if yes, exactly how? How about Hypothesis testing? How should we calculate the sample sizes for a machine learning model?

Comment: Hi @Ramin, please can you specifity the goal of your ML model? I understand it is to predict clients who (based on its history data) are likely to make purchases. After that, send an email to those users?

Comment: This is the problem: we have a set of marketing emails that we currently regularly send out to the members. Now, we would like to see using these email campaigns, which members will likely purchase miles and which ones will not. So we extract a lot of features from these emails like the time they were sent, day of the week they were sent, number of links in the emails, number of pictures in the emails, word counts of the emails, membership level, etc. Based on this feature space, we  build a binary classification model to see which members will purchase and which ones will not .......

Comment: ...... After we build the model, we observe the predictions and see some features help a lot and some others like having zero images in the body emails won't help, so we say okay let's add more images to the email body. we add more images to the email body and send emails with more images to some members and send the same old emails with no image number changes to some others to check if it really helped or not

Comment: ok so from what I understand, the interventation in this scenario is actually 'sending a new email', and your control group is sending the old email. Based on that, the question is: which clients will you send the new email to? I guess here is where your ML model comes into play: send the new email to the clients more prone to purchase (find the updated answer with this in mind)

Comment: How should the flow be? First, build the model using the current email and validate it using train, validation, test sets. Next, it would be to make changes and send a new email campaign to some members and not send to some others. Then push the model to production. At the end, how to do the validation of the ML model?

Comment: [1/2] from your latest comments, maybe the first question you should address is: which history info do we have about our clients? Can we make a model to predict which clients are prone to positively purchase based on some mail changes? If you want to build a supervised learning model, you need some prior history with mail changes (or similar info) which, in the past, was used with clients so you can define your target label "likely/not likely" to purchase

Comment: [2/2] If you do not have that past info, the best you can do is run the first email changes campaign, and still run your A/B tests, but not yet with any ML model (until you have enough history to build your target labels); other approach could be unsupervised learning to cluster clients based on some other info, but it is not that certain in this case I guess

Answer (score 1):

One way to go when applying a propensity machine learning model on marketing emails can be:

- build a machine learning (ML) model to predict which customers will more likely purchase, with a binary classifier
- depending on the marketing budget and contacting criteria, the email should be sent to clients who are more prone to behave as intended (i.e. purchasing afterall), but leaving some of those clients without intervention as a control group (where intervention means sending the new email, and not intervention is sending the old email):

[image]

With this scenario, you can:

- **evaluate your ML model performance** (once it is in production and once it has been already used for campaigns) with the selected metric (AUC, recall...) with the group of **clients who did not receive** any intervention (the new email in this case), it could be using B & D
- on the other hand, evaluate the **effectiveness of the campaign** comparing clients who received the new email VS who did not (A vs B), by using **hypothesis testing** with methods like **permutation tests**; your null hypothesis is that there is no actual difference (effect) in receiving VS not receiving the cmmunication, and you want to test whether it is actually false (i.e. rejecting this hypothesis confirming that the campaign is actually effective. You can follow these steps ([source of info](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/permutation_test/)):

1. Compute the difference of the considered statistic between sample A and B (n & m sizes)
2. Combine all measurements into a single dataset
3. Draw a permuted dataset from all possible permutations of the dataset in 2.
4. Divide the permuted dataset into two datasets A' and B' of sizes n and m
5. Compute the difference of these samples and record this difference
6. Repeat steps 3-5 until all (or sufficient) permutations are evaluated
7. Return the p-value as the number of times the recorded differences were at least as extreme as the original difference (steep from 1) and divide this number by the total number of permutations

Comment: What I don't understand about your response is why to use the clients who did NOT receive any intervention to evaluate ML model performance? So we use all the clients to build the ML model, then I thought to evaluate the model performance, we use a holdout set and we apply the ML model and check id this gives, for example, high F1 score, isn't it correct?

Comment: For evaluating the model performance, shouldn't we generally use a holdout/validation set from our historical data, and then check the model performance on that? if not, then what?

Comment: one point is evaluating your model on training phase (with the holdout set and so on, using your training clients info) and a later validation of your ML model is once it is in production and making predictions; in this case, you better do it using clients who did not receive the new email, so you can just evaluate your model without the possible effect of the campaign

Comment: But we have an existing email campaign, we build a model to see what needs to be changed and then make the changes in our new email campaign according to the insight we get from the model predictions. Then, how would this work in production? We productionize the model and this model basically makes suggestions on changes to be made to our email campaign. Then we make the changes to the email campaign after the production? Basically, I am very confused about the order of this flow

Comment: I guess my question is we push the model to production BUT in production we do not have the labels, right? Because, in production, we are not supposed to know which members actually purchase and which ones did not. We don't know that yet, is that correct? If this is correct, you mentioned to do the validation in production using the clients who didn't get the new email. Then how do we do the validation in production if we don't know the true target values?

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach to measuring the success of an intervention (e.g. email campaign) is running an A/B test. To get further insight as to what customer segments were more/less affected by the campaign you should use methods from the field of "uplift modeling". You can find tons of materials on that online.

To give an example, after running your A/B test you can use the "transformed outcome approach" where you calculate a new response variable $y^*=\frac{ y*I_{treated}}{p_{treated}}+ \frac{y*I_{\text{not treated}}}{p_{\text{not treated}}}$ and then you can run any ML model you like with $y^*$ as the target, and you'd get the expected treatment effect as a function of your predictor variables (e.g. country).

Here a few reads to get you started:

https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-uplift-modeling-introduction-6e14de32bfe0

https://towardsdatascience.com/uplift-modeling-e38f96b1ef60

I've also written an R package that utilizes the above approach in R:
https://github.com/IyarLin/segmenTree